# Ошибка при компиляции триггера: PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference not allowed in this context

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Есть такой код:

```
CREATE TABLE PODPISANT (
    "Number"                           NUMBER NOT NULL,
    scop_of_authority                  CHAR(1 char),
    status                             CHAR(1 char),
...
);

create trigger basis_of_authority_tg before insert on PODPISANT
begin 
  if PODPISANT.status = '3' and basis_of_authority_of_org is null then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'basis_of_authority_of_org для Статус=3. '||
      'Указываются основания полномочий (доверия) организации');
  end if;
end;
```

И после ккомпиляции тригера такая ошибка:

> PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'PODPISANT.STATUS'
> not allowed in this context

Что не так с тригером?

Comment: 1. Текст намекает, что нужен row-based триггер (т.е. проверять отдельно каждую вставляемую запись). Тогда должно быть `FOR EACH ROW`. 2. Для того, чтобы ссылаться на значения полей вставляемой записи (а не непонятно какой из записей всей таблицы), существует псевдотаблица `NEW`. 3. `basis_of_authority_of_org` - тоже поле в этой таблице?

Comment: @Akina да, в этой же таблице. Но теперь пишет что rise_application_error must be declared

Comment: Ну так я не в курсе, что это за функция и откуда она взята... разбирайтесь. Встроенной такой нет.

Comment: Это встроенная функция. Значения до 20000 зарезервированы под вывод системных ошибок, от 20001 до 20999 можно свои писать

Comment: Тогда Вы явно опечатались в её названии...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обращаться к значениям колонки в теле триггера можно только в строчном триггере с переменными типа запись (`rowtype`): `:OLD` и `:NEW`:

```
create table podpisant (
    "Number"          number not null,
    scop_of_authority char(1 char),
    status            char(1 char))
/    
create or replace trigger basis_of_authority_tg 
before insert on podpisant for each row
begin 
    if :new.status = '3' then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'basis_of_authority_of_org для Статус=3. '||
            'Указываются основания полномочий (доверия) организации');
    end if;
end;
/

insert into podpisant values (1, 'a', '3')
```

> ORA-20001: basis_of_authority_of_org для Статус=3. Указываются основания полномочий (доверия) организации